# How to render Vue component which is coming from an html field of my database?

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, components

Let admit, I have in my database a field "content" where I store a component and it's data to be show.
How can I render this component?

I know v-html to render the html but it didn't understand the component.

```
// My data coming from database:
// data.content = "<w-image slug="my-image-slug"></w-image>"

<template>
   <div v-html="data.content"></div> <!-- just show the html output -->
</template>
<script>
import WImage from '@/Components/Widgets/Image.vue'
...
export default {
   props:{
        data : Object,
        ...
    },
    components: {
        WImage,
        ...
    },
}
</script>
```

I guess it's not possible because it didn't compile the code.
But, I'm generally surprise of what's possible to do so...
I give it a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the info you provided I could imagine a solution, like this:

```js
Vue.component("WImage", {
  props: ['slug'],
  template: `
    <div>{{ slug }}</div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      htmlstring: "<w-image slug='my-image-slug'></w-image>"
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    return h({
      template: `<div>${ this.htmlstring }</div>`
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If you know the possible components beforehand, then you could register/dynamically import them to a component that handles all of the `HTML` strings. Use the `render` function to render the `HTML` strings by passing it a component object, with `template`.

You need the [full build of Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only) to do this trick - the normal build won't compile templates on the fly, so it won't work.